# Usage of fractional numbers

Tags: reading-aloud, numbers

I had a test yesterday. There was a question about fraction number and it's way of writing. What is the right form of spelling of "1/2 ton"? A half of ton, half of a ton or half a ton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say either:

> half a ton

or

> one half ton

Without an "of" in "1/2 ton", you can't say "half of a ton". "half of ton" is wrong because "ton" requires an article.

Comment: It means I shouldn't put "of" between "half" and "ton"?

Comment: Not when you are directly writing or saying "1/2 ton". I added some additional detail to my answer.

Comment: I disagree that you **can't** say "half of a ton" in fact I think that "half o' ton" is the shortened form of "half of a ton"

Comment: @Jim You can say it, but not as "1/2 ton" literally.

Comment: Ok, yes,right, for the OP's purpose you'd never write out "1/2 ton" as "half of a ton"

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.  Normally, you would probably say "half a ton", as in

> The ingot weighs half a ton.

However, if "1/2 ton" is an adjective, then you would write

> You need a forklift to move that half-ton ingot.